# Are questions about getting other editor like behavior in emacs on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This is related, but in the opposite direction of another question:

[Are questions about getting emacs-like behavior in other things on topic?](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27/are-questions-about-getting-emacs-like-behavior-in-other-things-on-topic)

Personally, I feel these types of questions should be on-topic as I've already asked one here:

[How to auto-save buffers when Emacs loses focus?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/how-to-auto-save-buffers-when-emacs-loses-focus)

But I figured it was worth asking as these types of questions could be contentious.

Comment: Why would such questions be contentious? I doubt that you will get any "no" answers here.

Comment: They're fine. Just remember to explain the feature well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe they are on-topic.

You are asking about how to provide feature `x` in Emacs.  The fact that the feature is in another editor/application already simply gives a better frame of reference for what behavior is desired.

I feel however that the question should still describe the desired behaviour well enough to be understood without knowledge of the other application/editor.

Answer (score 1):

Given that asking about some imaginary feature `X` is on-topic, I don't see how the fact that the feature is present in this or that editor renders it off-topic.

I personally see those kinds of questions interesting, specially for beginners. When I was learning Emacs, it was quite common for me to ask someone 'how can I do X-like thing from visual-studio in Emacs'. I could say most of the times someone told me the 'emacs-way' of doing the same task, which was not quite the same, but way superior.