# Are command-line editing interface on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Using emacs in shell is activated by default or by the following command:

```
set -o emacs
```

Are the questions about the shell commands on topic?

[Example 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102870/21471) (see comments): how to achieve some text conversion results using `emacs` mode, instead of using `vi`.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: [Example 1](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102870/21471) (see comments), how to achieve some text conversion results using `emacs` mode, instead of `vi`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This falls under the topic of emacs key bindings in an another application, in this case the bash shell.  As discussed in [Are questions about getting emacs-like behavior in other things on topic?](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27/2710), such questions are off topic on this site.